# Escape $ in filename

Tags: python, escaping

I have a list of files on my filesystem which I'd like to chmod to 664 via python.

On of the filenames/dirpaths (I am not allowed to change the filename nor dirpaths!!!) is:

/home/media/Music/Ke$ha/song.mp3 (NOTE $ is a literal, not a variable!)

I receive the files in a list: ['/some/path/file1', '/some/otherpath/file2', etc...]

If I try to run the following code:

files = ['/home/media/Music/Ke$ha/song.mp3']

for file in files:
    os.chmod(file, 0664)

It complains that it cannot find /home/media/Music/Ke$ha/song.mp3. Most likely (I guess) because the called shell tries to expand $ha, which is obviously wrong.

The 'Ke$ha' file is just an example, there are many more files with escape characters in it (e.g. /home/media/Music/Hill's fire/song.mp3)

The question I have is: How can I elegantly convince python and/or the shell to handle these files properly?

Kind regards,

Robert Nagtegaal.

Comment: I don't think `os.chmod()` involves the shell in any way. Are you sure that path is `/home/media/Music/...` and not `/home/<your username>/media/Music/...`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - yup, I can not reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
files=["/home/media/Music/Ke$ha/song.mp3", "/home/media/Music/Hill's fire/song.mp3"]

import os,re
os.system("chmod 777  " + re.escape(files[i]))
```

Comment: what does re.escape do exactly? (It escapes I get that!) I do like the elegance btw! I'll test.

Comment: it simply add escape character before special char like  $, ', /  .  go  check it  re.escape('abd$dh.txt')

Comment: It works, but I don't like the fact that you're doing a system call. But it works

Answer (score 0):

How about this, a raw string? Also is your username 'media'?

```
files = [r'/home/media/Music/Ke$ha/song.mp3']
```

Comment: This sollution doesn't work: >>> import re,os
>>> files=['./Ke$ha']
>>> os.chmod(r'%s' % files[0], 0664)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Ke$ha'